# How would I build a twisted water slide?

Tags: modeling

I can't seem to find a tutorial or explanation as to how to do it - I start off with a cylinder and don't really get anywhere.

[image]
[Something like this.](https://www.naturalstructures.com/aquatics/WaterSlides/Waterslide_Tunnel_1615_1254_g.jpg)

Any advice?

Comment: I think the Screw modifier might be the solution

Comment: Better use curves for something like this, at least for start, then you can convert to mesh, but please try to include the image in the question rather than keeping it as a link, question quality as it is now is very low, and might get flagged and removed.

Comment: yes you're right, array + curve modifers, so you have the joints

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

1. Using the Add Curve:Extra Objects shipped add-on, create a Spiral, Archimedes, 2 anticlockwise turns, type: Poly. Cut off the ends appropriately, and <kbd>E</kbd> extrude the new ends to make the straight sections.
2. Adjust the native Full bevel of the curve in its data tab, for depth and resolution. (object data tab > Shape and Geometry panels. Shape: 3D, Fill>Full.. and Geometry: Bevel>Depth and Bevel>Resolution)
3. In Object Mode <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> convert to mesh, then assign and apply a Solidify modifier
4. <kbd>K</kbd> with <kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Z</kbd> make a cut through the pipe, constrained to 45 degrees. Delete surplus faces and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > Bridge Edge Loops to repair the rim. Find or create a few edge loops round the outside skin, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>B</kbd> bevel them to the width of the joints. With the new face rings selected, <kbd>E</kbd> extrude, right-click to cancel transform, <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> scale the extrusion along its normals.

Then you can add a Bevel modifier by angle (segments 2, profile 1.0) to sharpen edges, and add a Subdivision Surface modifier.. unless you just want to stick with low-poly, and Auto Smooth by angle in the slide's data panel.

Comment: Thank  you so much for this, but I must be missing a step between 2 and 3.  I press Alt+C and add the Solidify mod, but the mod says 'Faces need for useful output' and there arn't any faces.

Comment: If you're in 2.8, the 'convert to mesh' shortcut is not  Alt-C, but in the right-click menu on the object.. is that the problem? Have you succeeded in creating a mesh?

Comment: okay, after creating the spiral, and converting the mesh (by right clicking > convert to mesh), then using the solidify mod, I get this: https://pasteboard.co/I8yzOpS.png

Comment: @Chud37  Ahh.. Step 2 is what creates the tube.. that's done by giving the curve a bevel in its object data tab > Shape and Geometry panels. Shape: 3D, Fill>Full.. and Geometry: Bevel>Depth and Bevel>Resolution. I'll try to make the answer clearer.

Comment: Aah thanks, that's perfect, I got it now!