# How do I add a screw modifier to an object made of several joined meshes?

Tags: screw-modifier

[image]

[image]

I am trying to create a twisted waterslide, and currently I have what is shown in the first image, which is just a cylinder joined to several toruses. Because I want to make the slide twisted, I tried to use the screw modifier, but the result was distorted no matter how much I made adjustments, since the screw modifier caused the original object to *widen and then twist upwards* instead of *elongating and twisting upwards at the opening of the slide*. I'm sure you know what is wrong with the 2nd image compared to an actual waterslide.

Is there something I'm doing wrong? How can I fix this, or are there any simpler alternatives to using the screw modifier to achieve what I am trying to do?

Comment: you need to use another method like Array + Curve modifier, with a spiral as curve

Comment: (Don't go too much by the name) The _Screw_ modifier generates new geometry. It doesn't just deform existing geometry. In other packages, it might be called something like 'Lathe'. _Simple Deform > Twist_  can deform geometry, but the suggestions that have been made here would be easier.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/136097/35559

Answer (score 1):

Add an archimedian curve:

[image]

with these settings:

[image]

add a cylinder, go to edit mode, press R Y 90, then add these modifiers:

[image]

and you will get:

[image]